# about data augmentation by cropping in the data layer of caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

In the data layer of caffe, how many images can be augmented if I used a `crop_size:227` for an `256*256` image. For example, in the `AlexNet`, the data layer is :

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 256
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

Is it `(256-227+1)*(256-227+1)=900` by cropping alone, and `900*2` by cropping and mirroring both?

If true, is this augmentation `(1->1800)` accomplished at once when each image is loaded? Or only one cropped image is generated every time when the original image is loaded, and the augmentation is just realized by running many epochs to train the network?